# Trying to get plain json response, but getting html

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

My problem is, that I'm trying to send a plain json response in Laravel Lumen, but I keep getting a HTML. How to disable the container?

Here is my Controller code:

```
public function getJson($id)
{
    return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
}
```

Here is my routes.php code:

```
$app->get('api/getJson/{id}','Controller@getJson');
```

and the `index.php` is here:

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';


$app->run($app->make('request'));
```

the received response is a html file with body and html, but I want just a plain JSON:

```
<html></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"name":"Abigail","state":"CA"}</pre></body><AutoScroll></AutoScroll></html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the response with headers and all.

Comment: Are you accessing the route directly from the browser? If so, make sure you don't have any extensions that modify the response. Try making the request from an incognito mode window to make sure there are no extensions enabled and see if the problem persists.

Comment: tried incognito, still getting the same

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue and it works fine. Do you have any middleware that might modify the response before sending it to the browser? If not, have you tried a different browser to rule out that the extra markup is not injected by the browser somehow?

Comment: yes, I tried it, it's really weird :(

Comment: Lumen doesn't inject any HTML into the responses by default, so it most likely is something specific to your application. You can create a new clean Lumen application and try sending the same response from a route and see if it persists. If it doesn't then it's clear that your application is the source, and to provide further help more information is needed, like any additional packages that you're using, the code for middleware you have defined that run for that particular request, the code for the controller you're returning the response from and any other information you deem relevant.

Comment: thank you very much, maybe I will try it, I'm a bit out of time :( I don't know what package could cause it, as far as I remember I haven't included nothing weird, but you never now

Comment: Are `getMedicine` and `getJson` methods just a post error?

Comment: @Laerte I tried to rename the functions to be more generic, but I was in a bit of hurry (you know, a hackaton :D) and I forgot to rename that one. In the original code the routes should be right, it produces no error. But thanks, I fixed the question